Stokes theorem for the Mobius band
This is probably a very simple question, but I really don't see the issue here. The Mobius band can be parametrised as
\begin{gather}
x(u,v) = (1 + \frac{v}{2} \cos{\frac{u}{2}}) \cos{u} \\
y(u,v) = (1 + \frac{v}{2} \cos{\frac{u}{2}}) \sin{u} \\
z(u,v) = \frac{v}{2} \sin{\frac{u}{2}}
\end{gather}
for $0 \leq u \leq 2\pi$ and $-1 \leq v \leq 1$. This means that the Mobius band is a singular 2-cube (up to a translation and a scale). Stokes theorem is known to hold for singular $k$-cubes. But it does not hold for the Mobius band. Why, if it is a singular 2-cube?

Great question! Is the image of the singular 2-cube actually the Möbius band? Analyze the boundary very carefully.

The issue is lack of orientability.

@TedShifrin, Upon analysing the boundary, I’ve figured that there is a straight line segment that is to be integrated over twice, so this singular cube, as it seems to me, is not a Mobius band, but much rather a twisted rectangle whose edges aren’t “glued”. This may still be wrong, but even if it is actually correct, I don’t seem to have enough intuition to grasp this fully. Maybe you  could suggest some good references to understand this better. Possibly one of your lectures available online or your book?

You got it. I don’t know any references, honestly. This lack of cancellation of that boundary piece is a consequence of the non-orientability of the Möbius band. You might search this site, though, because I believe this sort of thing has appeared before — what does flux of a force field across a Möbius band mean if we can’t globally define a continuous unit normal? You can also generalize Stokes’s Theorem to non-orientable manifolds by integrating densities instead of forms. That, too, has been discussed.

Yep, I was going to suggest that on non-orientable manifolds one should integrate densities. (Actually in oriented manifolds this works as well, but it is equivalent to the usual integration of n-forms, so there's not much to gain).
